# What languages are accepted in the PDA

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I'm struggling to understand the notation of push down automata's when pushing  and popping items on and off of stacks.

I understand that the stack must be empty for the string to be accepted.

Here is my PDA:

[image]

If I create a transition diagram for say input 0011 i would do it like this:

```
State          Input         Stack

q0             0011          ɛ

q0             011           0

q0             11            00

q0             1             100

q0             ɛ             1100
```

Since the input is empty and the stack is not empty, this is not accepted?

So if i put input like well thats the thing... I'm pretty sure this is wrong because if i put any string into the PDA it won't accept.

I guess to sum up my actual question, is the notation for the first non-terminal (0,ɛ/0)(1,ɛ\1) Does this mean to under input 0 add 0 to the stack (same for input 1, doing the opposite)?

For the second terminal does it mean under... Well this is what is confusing me (do i take strings out of the stack or the input?) I imagine i have to remove items from the stack?

So does this mean the language accepted by this PDA is the empty set? If not can you explain where i'm going wrong?

Comment: This PDA is for palindromes over `{0,1}`. The second state's transitions are saying "read a 0 as input, pop a 0 from the stack, do not add anything new to the stack". This is popping the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There are different conventions but one common convention is that you accept when:

1. The input is exhausted; and
2. You are an in accepting state; and
3. The stack is empty.

Really you could use several subsets of these rules, and use other sets of rules, and get systems that also work for context-free languages. Machines would have different interpretations in those systems but the expressive power would be the same.

Assuming the three-point system above, as Welbog points out, this PDA accepts the language of even-length palindromes over the alphabet `{0, 1}`. Let's talk about what each state does.

1. `q0` reads either `0` or `1` and pushes `0` or `1`, respectively, onto the stack, over and over again as long as you want. If you read string `x`, you push string `x` onto the stack.
2. `q1` reads either `0` or `1` and, if you have that symbol on top of the stack, pops it off, over and over gain as long as you want. If you read string `x`, you pop `x^R` off the stack.

If we make `q1` an accepting state, and require that the stack be empty when the input is exhausted, that implies:

1. We popped off `x^R`, if `x` was read while in state `q1`.
2. The stack contains `x^R` if we read `x^R` in state `q0`.
3. We read `x^R` and then `x` and accepted, so we only accept strings like `x^R x`, i.e. even-length palindromes
4. Moreover, any even-length palindrome has a path through this PDA which results in it being accepted, since the PDA can remain in `q0` for `|x|/2` input symbols, transition to `q1` and read the remaining `|x|/2`. Since the PDA is nondeterministic this is sufficient to say the string is accepted.